# Accessing values nested within dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary which contains dictionaries, which may also contain dictionaries, e.g.

```
dictionary = {'ID': 0001, 'Name': 'made up name', 'Transactions':
               {'Transaction Ref': 'a1', 'Transaction Details':
                  {'Bill To': 'abc', 'Ship To': 'def', 'Product': 'Widget A'
                      ...} ...} ... }
```

Currently I'm unpacking to get the 'Bill To' for ID 001, 'Transaction Ref' a1 as follows:

```
if dictionary['ID'] == 001:
    transactions = dictionary['Transactions']
        if transactions['Transaction Ref'] == 'a1':
            transaction_details = transactions['Transaction Details']
            bill_to = transaction_details['Bill To']
```

I can't help but think this is is a little clunky, especially the last two lines - I feel like something along the lines of the following should work:

```
bill_to = transactions['Transaction Details']['Bill To']
```

Is there a simpler approach for drilling down into nested dictionaries without having to unpack into interim variables?

Comment: The line you feel should work actually does.

Comment: Note that `0001` is not valid in Python3, neither is any number with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
bill_to = transactions['Transaction Details']['Bill To']
```

actually works. `transactions['Transaction Details']` is an expression denoting a `dict`, so you can do lookup in it. For practical programs, I would prefer an OO approach to nested dicts, though. `collections.namedtuple` is particularly useful for quickly setting up a bunch of classes that only contain data (and no behavior of their own).

There's one caveat: in some settings, you might want to catch `KeyError` when doing lookups, and in this setting, that works too, it's hard to tell which dictionary lookup failed:

```
try:
    bill_to = transactions['Transaction Details']['Bill To']
except KeyError:
    # which of the two lookups failed?
    # we don't know unless we inspect the exception;
    # but it's easier to do the lookup and error handling in two steps
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use something like this:

```
>>> def lookup(dic, key, *keys):
...     if keys:
...         return lookup(dic.get(key, {}), *keys)
...     return dic.get(key)
...
>>> d = {'a':{'b':{'c':5}}}
>>> print lookup(d, 'a', 'b', 'c')
5
>>> print lookup(d, 'a', 'c')
None
```

Additionally, if you don't want to define your search keys as individual parameters, you can just pass them in as a list like this:

```
>>> print lookup(d, *['a', 'b', 'c'])
5
>>> print lookup(d, *['a', 'c'])
None
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I added an edit to clarify the true dynamic search capability of this function.  The ability to pass in a list of search keys on-the-fly makes this a cut above the other techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Following is another way of accessing nested dictionaries

```
>>> dbo={'m':{'d':{'v':{'version':1}}}}
>>> name='m__d__v__version' # it'll refer to 'dbo['m']['d']['v']['version']', '__' is the separator
>>> version = reduce(dict.get, name.split('__'), dbo)
>>> print version
1
>>>
```

Here, variable 'name' refers to 'dbo['m']['d']['v']['version']', which seems much shorter and neat.

This method will not throw KeyError. If a key is not found then you'll get 'None'.

Ref.: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475156-using-reduce-to-access-deeply-nested-dictionaries/

Comment: It will throw a TypeError if you try name='m__foo__v__foo':
TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

You can access nested dictionaries with a tuple using `NestedDict`.

```
>>> from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict
>>> nested_dict = {"a": {"a": 0, "b": 1},
...                "b": {"a": 2, "b": 3}}
>>> nd = NestedDict(nested_dict)
>>> nd["a", "a"]
0
>>> nd["b", "a"]
2
>>> nd["a"]
{"a": 0, "b": 1}
```

To install [ndicts](https://github.com/edd313/ndicts):

```
pip install ndicts
```