# Extracting a value from a combination of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, biopython, ncbi

The `eutils` package form NCBI returns the below object for a specific request. From this I want to extract the value **245540**. How can I do that?

```
[{u'LinkSetDb'       : [{u'DbTo'     : 'sra',
                         u'Link'     : [{u'Id': '245540'}], 
                         u'LinkName' : 'biosample_sra'}],
  u'DbFrom'          : 'biosample', 
  u'IdList'          : ['1178400'], 
  u'LinkSetDbHistory': [],
  u'ERROR'           : []}]
```

Comment: As best as I can understand it, you're asking how to [access values inside nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700798/python-accessing-values-nested-within-dictionaries) which is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the variable name is var then var[0]['LinkSetDb'][0]['Link'][0]['Id']